# Unknown host to access ftp on new server

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to connect to an FTP through a new server by command line, but I am getting the following error: Unknown host. I can access same ftp through other machines. How can I do for allow this server access the FTP. ?

Comment: What's the command you're using?  From the limited information you've given, I'm going to guess you're trying to do something like `ftp ftpServerName` and that `ftpServerName` does not resolve.  You'll need to either use the IP address of the server, use a different DNS server, or modify your `hosts` file.  Another possibility is that the ftp server is on a different subnet, and is not accessible.

Comment: Yes, I am accessing via ftp ftpservername. I believe that is not accessible because the ping also fails.

Comment: How can i modify hosts ?

Comment: If you try nslookup servername and it fails you have a DNS problem. If it's resolving the ip address try tracert and see where it's getting lost.

Comment: just google for `modify hosts file windows` or whatever OS you're on, though I'd verify that you can connect via IP first.

Comment: Thank you guys. I don't connect via IP. No exists route to ftp.

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned in your comments, there were two issues:

1. You were trying to connect by a host name that didn't resolve
2. There is no route to the IP

For the first, modifying the hosts file would have been sufficient.

But, since you can't connect via IP, that means there's no route between the client and the FTP server.  If I were to guess, that means you're probably using an intranet address for the FTP server and that your new client is on a different intranet that the server.  To create a route from the client to the server will involve either putting the clients and the server on the same network or some port forwarding using either the routers or clients that can see both.